# How to find reward of total bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoind

I have been developing an application for few coins to get details of the coin, it's more like https://masternodes.online/, where we need to show the ROI, Nodes, required, Minimum Worth of a bitcoin, for those things, I need to find reward of bitcoin first.   Could you let me know how to find reward of bitcoin(not for single transaction) and with that how to calculate ROI and other stuff?

Comment: what do you mean "reward of bitcoin"?